# please suggest a good VIDEO PLAYING library for android

Tags: android

I am looking for a good video player ( library ) for android, which would be able to play video files onto a surfaceview or something, allowing me to overlay it with my own play/pause buttons, progress bar, etc.

What library would you suggest?

Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `VideoView`. Or, use `MediaPlayer` with your own `SurfaceView`. Both are built into Android.